# Help needed on calculated measures

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

Patron Revenue Cube:

In one of the calculated measures “Acutal Gross Profit”, there are four measures used  as

“[Measures].[Acutal Win]-[Measures].[Operator Pay]-[Measures].[Redeeming Dollars]-[Measures].[Redeeming Comp]”

The first two measures belong to vw_fact_patronrevenue  view  and the other two belong to vw_fact_patronredemption view.

Those two views do not have any foreign key relation to each other. They are related through dimension views.

To verify the calculated measure, I need to get the
 column_names for  the select statement (which I have),
table/view (i also have them)
joining column_names (which I don’t have, and how do I figure out which columns do I need for not-directly-related tables)
 There are however some  columns which are common to both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you don't need to write a single SQL statement to test your calculated measure. What you should do is to test each of the 4 raw measures, either independantly or in their measure groups.

When you know the 4 raw measures are correct you can then test your calculated measure "inside" the cube by displaying it alongside the 4 raw measures and checking that you have the arithmetic right.